# How to Connect Azure Mysql Database with Django Project

Tags: django, database, azure-mysql-database

I am trying to connect my Django project with the Azure Mysql database but it's showing this error continuously:

> RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dummyserver.database.windows.net' (timed out)")

and this is easily able to connect with the **Azure Data Studio**, don't know why it's not working in this Django Project.
even i am able to make the connection to the local Mysql Server and able to migrate the table and models, but when i am trying to do this with Azure Mysql database, then it's not working and I'm sure of all the details i put in the configuration.

i had also followed these links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-sql-db-django/azure-sql-db-django/

i just want to make this connection done and able to migrate all my models to the Azure Mysql database, with the help of my Django project.

Comment: Hi, can you please share a more detailed log for the error you are facing? Also check weather `'dummyserver.database.windows.net'` is set to the correct connection url.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Mitrajeet Golsangi comments. From the reference [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-sql-db-django/azure-sql-db-django/) and [git](https://github.com/azure-samples/azure-sql-db-django/tree/main/) I am able to connect to Connect Azure Mysql Database with Django Project.

For Azure  [SQL Server](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django).

```bash
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user@myserver',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

For Azure [Mysql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/connect-python#step-1-create-a-table-and-insert-data)

```bash
config = { 'host':'<mydemoserver>.mysql.database.azure.com',
 'user':'<myadmin>@<mydemoserver>', 
 'password':'<mypassword>', 
 'database':'<mydatabase>', 
 'client_flags': [mysql.connector.ClientFlag.SSL],
  'ssl_ca': '<path-to-SSL-cert>/DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem' 
  }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Sampath Thanks alot for you Response, i need to ask one thing that as you mentioned above two Configs One for Mysql and Another SQL Server so they both different or they both need to do , means i am little confused because i am trying to connect to Mysql so it means i only need to do the MYSQL Configuration...
Right?

Comment: @JimLarry we do not need both I will Remove the SQL Server Configs. If you use MySQL [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-connector/how-to-integrate-mysql?tabs=django#sample-codes-2) use MYSQL configs only.

Comment: Hii Sampath, i am using SQL Server and also using the same config you had given but now getting some additional error, of missing file along with this i also wanted to let you know i am doing all these stuff in Mac, 

file mising error belongs to something like this {libodbc.2.dylib} this file not found at appropriate Location or Path

Comment: @JimLarry please flow the git configuration to avoid [error](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django)